# Properties overriding with profile in different .properties files than application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a bunch of `.properties` files. For example:

```
application.properties
foo.properties
bar.properties
```

These are my default properties.

I also have a profile `demo` and I'd like it to use the above properties as well as override some of them in its own `.properties`.

```
application-demo.properties
foo-demo.properties
bar-demo.properties
```

So let's say that `application.properties` looks like that:

```
some.property=ABC
some.other.property=true
```

While `application-demo.properties` has the following content:

```
some.other.property=false
```

Then, combining the default `application.properties` it results in such setting:

```
some.property=ABC
some.other.property=false
```

This seems to work. However, the analogous situation doesn't for other `.properties` files like `foo.properties`: the `foo-demo.properties` will not override `foo.properties` if there are properties specified. It's like it just isn't taken into account.

How can I change it without having to define separate profiles and just copy-pasting with changes in the desired places, and maintaing this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify -Dspring.config.name=application,bar,foo in jvm properties and config spring.profiles.active=demo in application.properties